# Why doesn't the php cli add linebreaks after `echo` commands?

Tags: php, interactive-shell

Since upgrading to php 5.4, issuing echo commands no longer includes automatic line breaks. In order to get similar behavior, you must now append your own; otherwise, you get the prompt on the same line as your output.

```
php > echo "some output";
some outputphp >

some outputphp > echo "some output", "\n";
some output
php >
```

Is there a configuration option to turn them on?

Comment: are you trying with `php -a` mode?

Comment: I am using -a (interactive mode). I often use it to test assumptions before coding them into unit tests.

Comment: @BryanAgee Try loading the old `php.ini` by specifying `--php-ini=/path/to/old/file` and see if that makes any difference. At least then you can confirm whether or not it's something built into PHP or something configurable in the `php.ini`